Take a single JSON object and divide it into multiple JSON objects. make API calls concurrently
The data I received is a large dynamic JSON, and I need to split it into multiple JSON objects to make API requests dynamically in Java. Each api call passes 30 objects in maximum. So if the total number of object is 500, then it requires to make multiple api calls.
Initially, some users receive 11 objects in the JSON dynamically, while others receive 25.
The process involves splitting the single JSON into multiple JSON objects and then making the API call.
{"total":11, "plist":[
{ 
  "reference" : "ABCDE123455432101",
  "date" : "01/01/2021",
  "value" : 111,
},{ 
  "reference" : "ABCDE123455432102",
  "date" : "02/02/2022",
  "value" : 222,

},{ 
  "reference" : "ABCDE123455432103",
  "date" : "03/03/2023",
  "value" : 333,

},{ 
  "reference" : "ABCDE123455432104",
  "date" : "04/04/2024",
  "value" : 444,

},{ 
  "reference" : "ABCDE123455432105",
  "date" : "05/05/2025",
  "value" : 555,
},{ 
  "reference" : "ABCDE123455432106",
  "date" : "06/06/2026",
  "value" : 666,

},{ 
  "reference" : "ABCDE123455432107",
  "date" : "17/08/2027",
  "value" : 777,

},{ 
  "reference" : "ABCDE123455432108",
  "date" : "08/08/2028",
  "value" : 888,

}
,{ 
  "reference" : "ABCDE123455432109",
  "date" : "09/09/2029",
  "value" : 999,
}
,{ 
  "reference" : "ABCDE123455432110",
  "date" : "09/10/2029",
  "value" : 100,
}
,{ 
  "reference" : "ABCDE123455432110",
  "date" : "09/10/2029",
  "value" : 100,
}
}]

My question is how to prepare dynamic API call based on JSON payload size? Each API call need to send maximum 30. So, validate the incoming payload size and make dynamic API call with 30 objects

How to prepare dynamic api call based on json payload size. Each api call need to send maximum 30.

@AndrewYim: yes, it is updated now

So what did you try? how did you try? what did not work? at what point? I think you should familiarize yourself with the guidelines of StackOverflow about asking question correctly

JSON object is already contains parts that you want to retrieve somewhere on the user interface. [MRE] is necessary to see how did you do it so far.

Are these API calls sent simultaneously? Or sequentially?
